# Will there be any security issues when storing mongodb document id in the javascript global variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am working on a project where I need to store the document id in the javascript global variable and update the id. Although it is not exposed in the URL but I am a bit worried whether if someone opens the source code and get the document ID and performs something malicious. Is it safe to do what I am doing ?.

Comment: Client side code should never be able to directly update something in your database.

Comment: How would they be able to do something to it in the db from the client?

Comment: It could give away details about your application's internal structure, but it should not be a security issue. An actual security issue would be when anyone could access your database (with or without document ids, that doesn't matter).

Comment: It's actually kind of an epidemic here that we do get a lot of questions where people posting them remove or obfuscate the `ObjectId` value from sample documents in a question. I think what *scares* people are the two lines *"a 3-byte machine identifier, a 2-byte process id,"*. So much so that current documentation does not actually say that anymore and says *"5-byte random value"*. But the possibility that anyone could use that data for a "hacking exploit" is pretty infinitesimal.

Comment: Moreover those 5-bytes have [actually changed.](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/objectid.js#L177-L182). So in most driver implementations those bytes truly are random, and nothing about the machine or process anymore.